# Making an android app that can make a connection between two android devices

Tags: android

I am a complete newbie in android development.I want to make an app that can connect my android smartphone to my android tablet.I want to be able to send/receive some stuff between both devices such as a live video feed from the android phone to the tablet, GPS coordinates from the phone to the tablet and so on. I want the connection to be over WiFi or Bluetooth or 3G. I want to know if such app is possible, In a positive case, where should I start to achieve my goal?.I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can start by reviewing [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,do you recommend any books that can help me achieve my goal ?

Comment: "Beginning Android" is a good source, but [here](http://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/android) is a list of different books you could find useful.